# ResultSet using query arguments like in jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, jdbc, parameters

Haven't found in docs.

Does java ResultSet supports query arguments,like jdbcTemplate?

For example, something like:

```
int length = 10;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select MyTable.COLOR from MyTable where MyTable.LENGTH = ?", new Object[] { length });
```

is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: ResultSet isn't supposed to query database, so why would it need query arguments?

Comment: i just found method of jdbcTemplate queryForRowSet.
Seems that what i need? because returned values of my sql is more than one rows.

Comment: You use `Statement` to fire a SQL query, not `ResultSet`. The `Statement` has a subclass which does exactly this, the `PreparedStatement`. See Bozho's answer for detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) allows (numbered) parameters:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
      "select MyTable.COLOR from MyTable where MyTable.LENGTH=?");

pstmt.setInt(1, desiredLength);

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Hi,Bozho. I'm interested in returned value - that will be multiple rows from DB table, selected by one ID param.

Comment: Just iterate through the `ResultSet` the usual way using `ResultSet#next()` in a `while` loop. That's also covered in one of the chapters of the aforementioned tutorial.

Comment: And this is the goal of my question- how to get ResultSet with argument ID in query. as i understand, this way isn't possible:

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select MyTable.COLOR from MyTable where MyTable.id = ?", new Object[] { id });